# Android XML <style> closing tag

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am learning to develop Android applications using Eclipse.  My application is for Android 3.0 and higher only. I am using the Google tutorials, found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) and have stumbled a little on the tutorial which helps us style the action bar.

if you follow the above link, you will see that Google suggests we style the action bar by creating an xml file called "/res/values/themes.xml and coding it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <style>
</resources>
```

I immediately noticed the lack of closing `</style>` tags. And so did Eclipse (this won't compile) Can anyone tell me why the `<style>` tags are not closed?

I tried simply closing the tags myself, which seemed to fix the trouble, though 2 other errors appeared:
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name `'@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.`
and

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

How do I include the appropriate resources to clear these errors?

Comment: I can't imagine no closing tag would be right... It's not valid XML. I want to believe the docs are wrong, but I'm not home to check an existing android project if <style> has a closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page of the Android documentation appears to be wrong, and I must assume it's simply a mistake.

If you look at other pages, for example: [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), the closing tag is properly denoted as `</style>`. [Platform themes](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) are also correctly formatted.

**Edit:** It appears the documentation has since been fixed.

Comment: Thanks Will. I suspected as much, though I'm surprised to see such an error in the official docs.  Do you have any insights on the missing resources errors mentioned in my question?

Comment: @GRY `DarkActionBar` is only available on API 14+ I believe. At API 11, you only have `Theme.Holo.Light` and `Theme.Holo.Dark`. You might look into using `ActionBarCompat` (which recently came out) and it's related themes if you're interested in earlier support.